# Kendo-UI and Cross-site Scripting

Tags: kendo-ui, xss

I am having a look at Kendo UI's widgets, and I can't find any reference to how they protect against XSS attacks in their documentation.

Any idea of how this works?.

Cheers.

Comment: This might help you: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/preventing-xss

Comment: Thanks but that is just for the Editor, does not say too much about the other widgets/elements :(

Answer (score 0):

In the end you have to do this on the server side. If you are on .NET you can use the [AntiXSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library) nuget package.

If you don't want to integrate it yourself I can recommend [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/)

HTH